# Nginx doesn't send certificate chain

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, tls

I've got the following certificate (first one is my own, the other two are from Comodo PositiveSSL):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And the following nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  tiendaganadera.com www.tiendaganadera.com;
        root         /var/www/tiendaganadera.com;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            index index.php;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

    rewrite ^/tienda/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    if ($request_uri ~ /(Smarty-2.6.19|payment|admin|provider|partner)/) {
        break;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~ \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico)$) {
        break;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /dispatcher.php last;
    }

}

server {
        listen       443 default ssl;
        server_name  tiendaganadera.com www.tiendaganadera.com;
        root         /var/www/tiendaganadera.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/tiendaganadera.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tiendaganadera.com.key;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
            index index.php;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
        #
        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

    rewrite ^/tienda/(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    if ($request_uri ~ /(Smarty-2.6.19|payment|admin|provider|partner)/) {
        break;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~ \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico)$) {
        break;
    }

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /dispatcher.php last;
    }

}
```

But I run  openssl s_client -connect tiendaganadera.com:443 -servername tiendaganadera.com and it outputs:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = tiendaganadera.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = tiendaganadera.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = tiendaganadera.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=tiendaganadera.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=tiendaganadera.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, prime256v1, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2043 bytes and written 402 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 48003BE87D4EA04D8F60A4838BF7CC4B0FAA821A4ABF2347726E9D86BAAFEC8F
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: CB66470AC61552D63B68EB78678A210CC1AFF4175B25E4FEFB6A9A416CA4FE0A191487F3EE432B4FB88FF3E171A46452
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 67 37 af 40 7d b4 06 5e-92 ed 10 a1 eb cf fd c8   g7.@}..^........
    0010 - 4d a4 b7 1a 39 e0 04 e4-dc b5 c0 65 aa 60 0e f7   M...9......e.`..
    0020 - 86 91 24 b3 d8 54 48 47-12 94 02 ae 0a 4f e7 d0   ..$..THG.....O..
    0030 - 63 1a c6 56 59 b0 a2 74-73 57 9d b5 76 b8 04 39   c..VY..tsW..v..9
    0040 - 88 fb 4f bb 6b a6 e2 c2-92 a3 36 22 d1 7c 51 8f   ..O.k.....6".|Q.
    0050 - 9a e6 ab 94 a5 a5 51 6d-0a 8c 6d 24 af 9b ac 9b   ......Qm..m$....
    0060 - 0e 57 d6 27 94 86 9f 09-b3 54 7a b5 00 30 19 6d   .W.'.....Tz..0.m
    0070 - 4c 25 67 45 f5 74 e7 24-c7 02 bc c0 8f 10 38 76   L%gE.t.$......8v
    0080 - 20 98 7e e6 05 f8 1d da-68 aa b2 66 3d f9 2b 5b    .~.....h..f=.+[
    0090 - cf 6b 6f 7f d7 1e f2 77-7c b9 8b 32 0a 6d 8a 18   .ko....w|..2.m..
    00a0 - 99 61 ce b1 a3 ce 97 aa-6b 4e 32 06 eb 14 67 9f   .a......kN2...g.

    Start Time: 1423599873
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
```

So nginx is only sending the first, apparently. Why is that?

Comment: Try removing the blank line between the certificates.

Comment: That obviously doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the following certificates in your list (in that order):

```
 #L Subject: ... CN=tiendaganadera.com
    Issuer:  ... CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA

 #A Subject: ... CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
    Issuer:  ... CN=AddTrust External CA Root

 #B Subject: ... CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
    Issuer:  ... CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority

 #R Subject: ... CN=AddTrust External CA Root
    Issuer:  ... CN=AddTrust External CA Root
```

Obviously, the order does not match. The first certificate #L is correctly the leaf certificate. But the following certificate #A does not sign #L as you can see from the fact that the subject of #A does not match the issuer of #L. Instead #B signs #L and #A signs #B and #R signs #A. #R then is the root certificate which should not be included at all.

To fix:

- leaf #L as the first
- move #B up so that it is directly after #L
- move #A down so that it is directly after #B
- remove #R because the root certificate should not be included (will be usually ignored if included but it is bad style).

Comment: The same happens with this: https://gist.github.com/autrilla/9019eebffaa00a79ffc9 which I think is what you suggested.

Comment: @zyngawow You did not remove the root certificate as pointed out. Remove blank lines too (bad practice).

Comment: And make sure you use this file (with the correct chain) as `ssl_certificate` in all places. So far you've only shown that you've got the certificates and not where you've stored them and you also did not show the complete config with all the includes. Make also sure that you've restarted the server. Do an explicit stop and a start of the server to make sure that it does not continue because of configuration errors somewhere else, which can happen if you just try a simple restart.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich how did you get the order info like Subject and Issuer? and how to change the order?

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x: *"how did you get the order info like Subject and Issuer?"* - I took the list of shown certificates and checked each one with `openssl x509 -text ...` . One can also check a running server with `openssl s_client -connect ...`. *"how to change the order?"* - this need to be fixed in the server, details depend on the server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich sorry i'm new to Nginx, i've been scratching my head how to change the order. do you have guide or reference? btw, thanks for `openssl s_client -connect ...` I managed to see the chain like in your sample and saw what's wrong in the order. thanks!

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x: nginx takes the order from the files you've configured. In any case it is a bad idea to have such a discussion in the comments of an 6 year old answer. Please ask a new question with full details if you need help.